# Hide/Show Bootstrap's Affix Navigation bar on hover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anyone knows how to hide/show Bootstrap's affix bar on hover?

```
$('#nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('header').height() // or a value
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured it out using css only!

```
.navbar.affix {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar.affix:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar.affix .navbar-nav {
  display: none;
}
.navbar.affix:hover .navbar-nav {
  display: block;
}
```